# Parse a Json Table to a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsarray

for the moment I fill in my array directly by a native objective-C code :

```
Datas *pan1 = [[Datas alloc] initWithTitle:@"My array 1" title:@"Shakespeare's Book" location:@"London"];
Datas *pan2 = [[Datas alloc] initWithTitle:@"My array 2" title:@"Moliere's Book" location:@"London"];


  NSMutableArray *datasListe = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:pan1, pan2, nil];
```

But I want to fill this NSMutableArray by this Json list :

```
{
    "myIndex" : [
              {
              "name":"My array 1",
              "title": "Shakespeare's Book",
              "location": "London"
              },
              {
              "name":"My Array 2",
              "title": "Moliere's Book",
              "location": "Paris"
              }
                ]
}
```

Anyone have ideas? Thanks much!

Comment: What did you try doing so far?

Comment: What you have is an "object" (dictionary) containing a single entry named "myIndex" and containing an array of several more "objects".  See json.org to understand the syntax.  Use NSJSONSerialization to convert to Objective-C objects.

Comment: for the moment I can display the whole Json datas. I know how to get datas from "title" for exemples. But I can't get all the "title" datas and put them in an Array

Comment: (This is incredibly easy if you simply try to understand it and understand that JSON structures map directly to Objective-C arrays and dictionaries.  Incredibly difficult if you attempt to blindly follow examples you find online.)

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON yet -- run it through NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Again, go to json.org and study the syntax.  Literally you can understand it all in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I will see that. But will I have to create a loop to fill the array?

Comment: If you parse the JSON and then access the "myIndex" element of the outer dictionary you will get an array back.  If that array suits you, use it.  If not, copy it's contents elsewhere.  It's only code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This json data can be parse very easily like this.

```
NSError *e;
NSArray *dic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsondata options:  NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
NSMutableArray *datasListe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *data = [dic objectForKey:@"myIndex"];
//Now you have array of dictionaries 
for(NSDictionary *dataDic in data){
NSString *name = [dataDic objectForkey:@"name"];
NSString *title = [dataDic objectForKey@"title"];
NSString *location = [dataDic objectForKey@"location"];
Datas *pan= [[Datas alloc] initWithTitle:name title:title location:location];
[dataList addObject:pan];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *firstDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Raja", @"name",
                            @"Developer", @"title",
                            @"USA", @"location",
                            nil];

  NSDictionary *secondDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Deepika", @"name",
                            @"Engieer", @"title",
                            @"USA", @"location",
                            nil];

NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr addObject:firstDictionary];
[arr addObject:secondDictionary];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonArray as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: My impression is that he wants to go the other way -- he has the JSON and wants to extract the data.