# Display Data with JSON result in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**I'm stuck! I want to display the data result in a tableView.I created a class with the same attributes . should i iterate eache key and store it in a NSArray?! What i should do now?**

```
NSDictionary *result =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestHandler options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

.

```
2015-07-29 17:55:12.669 Test[9051:173867] {
0 = 200;
data = (
        {
            name = "John";
            lasta_name = "Frusciante"
            "avatar" = "https://pictures.com/2516137_1185214515_1677640606.png";
            "descripcion" = "Guitar player";
        },
        {

            name = "Chad";
            lasta_name = "Smith"
            "avatar" = "https://pictures.com/2516137_1185214515_1677640606.png";
            "descripcion" = "Drummer";
        },
        {

            name = "Flea";
            lasta_name = "Balzary"
            "avatar" = "https://pictures.com/2516137_1185214515_1677640606.png";
            "descripcion" = "Bass player";
        },
        {
            name = "Anthony";
            lasta_name = "Kiedis"
            "avatar" = "https://pictures.com/2516137_1185214515_1677640606.png";
            "descripcion" = "Vocalist";
        }
)
```

}

Comment: You don't display JSON in a TableVIew.  You extract the JSON into a TableViewDataSource and display the extracted data.  The fact that it originated as JSON (or Pig Latin) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a class you can construct that class with each of the objects and store that in an array.

Then use the array of objects you just created to populate the tableview

This is a very good answer that demonstrates the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21207931/2803660

Comment: Thanks man! it helped me a lot! 
And also i used this reference: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218492/2946824

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you must convert the JSON to a NSArray.

A awesome way is using Mantle to convert the JSON to instance of your class.
https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle

code is like this

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"imageUrlString"      : @"icon",
             @"smallImageUrlString" : @"icon_small",
             @"desc"                : @"title",
             };
}
```

in your class, left is property of your class and right is JSON key
and `NSArray *array = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:[YourClass class] fromJSONArray:JSONArray error:nil]` where you need to use.

Then you can use the array as data source of the tableView.